Module not available in spyder console in a remote server
In spyder, I open a console in a remote server. When I try to import modules, for example matplotlib,  they are not available.
What I have tried?
In my account in the remote server, I created a virtual environment and pip-installed the modules I need in that virtual environment. I then included "source /path-to-virtualenv/bin/activate" in my .bashrc in my home in the remote server, hoping to run the spyder console using this virtual environment. But it did not work.
I also tried to follow this stack: How can I import a module dynamically given the full path?
This did not work either.
